# (Powequery) How to call different functions based on a list of tables

Tags: powerquery

I have a list of tables in Powerquery after partitioning from an original big table. I am trying to perform a nested join on each of the tables. Each of the 3 tables will have its own nested join, although the tables joined to and the key-containing columns are different for each table. Eg. List contains table1, table2,table3, table1 to be joined to Table A with table1[Host] as the key, table2 to be joined to Table B with table2[Location] as the key, table3 to be joined to Table C with table3[Name] as the key.

I can do the joins on each table separately (as opposed to having a list of tables), and then combine the output, but it gets unwieldy if there are many tables to be joined. Was wondering if there is a "neater" way to do so.

On a related note, is it possible to invoke different functions (1 function for each table in a list of tables), and how?

Cheers

Comment: Why not write functions to address the original data table? averageif() etc

Comment: Hi Mike, i'm not proficient in M, could you give an example of functions that could be invoked on the original data table to give the desired result (i.e. merging a part of the original data table - table1 - with Table A, another part - table2 - with Table B, and the final part - table3 with Table C)?

Comment: Sirry, don’t know M, but excel has a function reference which explains each function, also I suggested working with the original data not multiple tables.

Comment: Mike, I need to use Powerquery (M) to achieve this. If it were to be done in excel then I could just use If, Vlookup and Choose to select the lookup array.

Comment: Also check out index() with match() as an alternative to vlookup and choose.

Comment: Yes Mike, but your proposal doesn't solve my problem. The solution has to be in Powerquery. For one thing, excel has row limitations and is more resource expensive.

Comment: Well you tagged Excel, so Excel solutions are valid...